# Can QNetworkProxy::setHostname accept IP adresses?

Tags: qt, proxy, qt5, qt5.4

I have a QNetworkProxy where I also set the Hostname via

```
QNetworkProxy * currentProxy = new QNetworkProxy();
currentProxy->setHostName("123.234.123.234");
```

But I do not get any conenction. I guess the method does not take any IP adresses?

Comment: I never set proxy explicitly but read it from the system:     QNetworkProxyFactory::setUseSystemConfiguration(true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard Qt examples they use this method like:

```
 QNetworkProxy proxy;
 proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::Socks5Proxy);
 proxy.setHostName("proxy.example.com");
 proxy.setPort(1080);
 proxy.setUser("username");
 proxy.setPassword("password");
 QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(proxy);
```

But actually host name can be passed as IP address:

```
QNetworkProxy proxy;
proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::HttpProxy);
proxy.setHostName(QString("http://192.168.1.1"));
proxy.setPort(8080);
QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(proxy);
```

You should check the proper settings of your system first of all.